# Representing functions as power series and finding interval of convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a bit confused about some minor reduction points about determining power series from functions and finding their interval of convergence. Here are some problems:

in general, I can't reduce $2*(-1)^n$ to $(-2)^n$ right? What are the rules again? Different exponents and different bases just have to be left separately?

As a given, I know that:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

For following functions, find interval of convergence and power series:

**1.** $$f(x) = \frac{5}{1-4x^2}$$

So this = $5 \cdot \frac{1}{1-4x^2} = 5 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (4x^2)^n$

So that right side is a geometric series and converges if $|4x^2| < 1$ or $|x^2| < \frac{1}{4}$ or $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$ right?

rewriting:

$$5 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (4^n)x^{2n}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 5 \cdot (4^n)x^{2n}$$

and since a = 0, the interval of convergence = $\frac{-1}{2} \lt x \lt \frac{1}{2}$ where a is what the power series is centered around which is 0 in this case.

**2.** $$\frac{2}{3-x}$$

$$ = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3-x} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3(1-\frac{x}{3})} = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{-x}{3})^n$$

that's a geometric series with \frac{-x}{3} = r and so $|\frac{-x}{3}| \le 1$ -> $-3 \lt x \lt 3$ right?

rewriting:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}} x^n$$

Is that right? Can the $2(-1)^n$ not be reduced further?

**3.** $$\frac{4}{2x+3}$$

$$ = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{2x+3} = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{3(1+\frac{2}{3}x)}$$

$$ = \frac{4}{3} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{-2x}{3})^n$$

So this is a geo series with $r = \frac{-2x}{3}$ right? So $|\frac{-2x}{3}| \le 1$ so $\frac{-3}{2} \lt x \lt \frac{3}{2}$

rewriting:   $$ \frac{4}{3} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{-2^n}{3^n})x^n$$

$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (4 \cdot \frac{-2^n}{3^{n+1}})x^n$$

Is that right? Can the 4 at the beginning not be pulled in?

Comment: You tell me: is $2\times(-1)^2$ the same as $(-2)^2$?

Comment: I say: is $2\times(-1)^2$ the same as $(-2)^2$?